# How to avoid a redirect loop in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, infinite-loop

In certain error conditions I would like to redirect to the Home controller but I want to make sure that I don't get into a "redirect" loop (with an exception being generated each time resulting in yet another redirect).  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea to redirect to the home controller on all exceptions if the home controller itself is a notorious exception thrower.

Comment: Not notorious... just possible

Comment: Can you give an example of an error on the home controller that you would want to redirect to the home controller, and one where you want to redirect to a different controller (like an error controller)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a solution to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) (i.e. "I want to redirect to self on exceptions but not if subsequent call will always throw an exception").

Barring implementing research in this field (while the halting problem is impossible to solve, you can eliminate quite a few cases with certain analysis) I would say your best bet is to do what firefox is doing anyway - keep a count of how many self-redirects have occurred and stop redirecting if it exceeds a certain count.

A way to do this might be to include a parameter that is incremented with each subsequent "exception throw redirect" and to compare against this parameter when deciding whether to redirect or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the general way to stop recursion is with a stop case. In your example, whatever does the redirect could look at its referrer, and make sure it does not try to "redirect" to the referrer.

Comment: Actually, that is not what I want.  Sometimes there is a condition where there is an exception but I want to redirect even if it's referred from the same URL, because the next time it will succeed.  I just don't want to keep doing it forever.

Comment: I cannot in good conscience help out with that. It would be like giving a dinosaur directions to the La Brea Tar Pits.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't redirect to the home controller.

Instead redirect to a static error message page.

This will be cleaner and more stable.

Comment: Even if it can solve a particular error you have in mind, what if the home page throws an exception you hadn't planned for? The you will be back to a redirect loop again. Think about it in terms of [Defensive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) to understand where I'm coming from.